# Where the configuration file of unity launcher is located?

Tags: unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find a Unity configuration file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52025/where-can-i-find-a-unity-configuration-file)

Where the configuration file of unity launcher is located? Settings which are available through dconf-editor. (desktop-> unity-> launcher).
Sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GSettings/dconf works with a single file located at ~/.config/dconf/user - you cannot edit that directly, but either via dconf-editor or the `gsettings` command.