# Change Dash home width

Tags: 12.04, unity-dash

I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Unity 2D on my netbook.
I will see Dash home full screen (main menu on all display). How can I change its width?

Answer (score 1):

[MyUnity](https://launchpad.net/myunity) allows you to make many customizations to Unity including changing the Dash size. OMGUbuntu has several good articles [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/tag/myunity)

**EDIT**

You may be able to find info [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52025/where-can-i-find-a-unity-configuration-file) for editing the configuration directly. I'm not at my Ubuntu box right now, so I can't tell you if gconfeditor has settings for the Dash's size.

Comment: Thanks! I don't like to install several apps in my system. I want to change this property in file by my hands.

Comment: See my edit, it links out to an answer on how to configure Unity using out-of-the-box tools