# Unity Panel Disappeared After Losing My Home Folder

Tags: unity

I had my home folder on it's own virtual disk that got corrupted and I lost the data on it. I was able to recreate my home folder in the same place, but now when I log into Ubuntu I get an empty screen and then I have to run ctrl-alt-t to get a terminal and then unity --reset to get the unity panel back and then all is well.  How can I fix things so I get the panel when I log in?  I'm running 12.04

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved although I'm not sure what caused it.  It was quite simple; at the password prompt to log in, just above and to the right is an icon to choose the login options.  That was set to 'User Defined Session'.  By simply choosing Unity instead I was able to log in and the unity panel displays as normal.  I never created any kind of user defined session in the past that I know of but after choosing the Unity option just one time it's now become the default, so everything is back to normal.
Thanks Superaxander

Answer (score 0):

Try reseting you're home directory. 
Steps:
First type this in terminal
sudo nano /etc/passwd
Then when you find yourself(you're user) it will look a bit like this:
jack:x:1000:1000:Jack,,,:/home/jack:/bin/bash
Change the /home/jack to a new place for you're home directory.
jack:x:1000:1000:Jack,,,:/mynewhome:/bin/bash
Make sure the folder you choose exists!

Press ctrl+x and then y and enter
You might need to relog or reboot but I don't know

Hope it helped!

Cheers

Comment: Hi Superaxander!  Thanks so much for taking the time to answer my question.  I'm sorry I wasn't clearer but I did recreate my home folder in the same location.  I've updated my question to reflect that.  My assumption is that there's some kind of configuration that was in the home folder that got erased but not recreated, although my assumptions aren't always that great :).  Blessings.

Comment: [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/52025/where-can-i-find-a-unity-configuration-file) look at this answer. Maybe try editing the settings and maybe it will create the files.