# How do I backup unity tweak settings?

Tags: 14.04, backup, unity-tweak-tool

Is a backup of the home folder enough?

All that I could find is `~/.config/unity-tweak-tool` which only contains `debug.log`. However, I'm aware that the actual settings that this tool configures are actually elsewhere; are all those config files stored in the home folder aswell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There is no real configuration file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52025/where-can-i-find-a-unity-configuration-file).

> Unity and Compiz are using GConf to store their settings.  GConf is a
>   configuration store that provides an API for applications to read and
>   write configuration information and receive notifications when
>   configuration items change.  The configuration data is saved under
>   `~/.gconf`, but modifications should only be made through the GConf
>   daemon.
>
> You can modify the Unity settings directly using `gconf-editor` and
>   browsing to `/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options`.  You
>   will notice that Unity responds to changes instantly, the same as
>   CCSM.
>
> If you want a command line tool to modify these settings, use
>   `gconftool-2`.  For example, to reduce the launcher icon size I can
>   do:
>
> ```
> gconftool-2 --set /apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/icon_size --type int 32
> ```

The GConf file seems as it shouldn't be messed with.

A better alternative would be either a.) resetting that specific page with the button if something goes wrong or b.) taking a screenshot. As far as the sliders, IIRC they should have a tooltip attached, although I'm not positive.

You really shouldn't be worried about corrupting something, but if you do (very unlikely), it shouldn't be that hard to reset Unity.